# What Node.JS-specific files and folders are usually excluded via .gitignore?

Tags: git, node.js

I'm a newbie Node.JS developer...

What do developers usually exclude from their Node.JS git repositories in production via .gitignore?

node_modules? bin? Etc...

Answer (score 109, accepted):

GitHub has [created a repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore) to answer this kind of questions for several languages/frameworks, including one for NodeJS.

https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore

Here is the current one for reference :

```
lib-cov
*.seed
*.log
*.csv
*.dat
*.out
*.pid
*.gz

pids
logs
results
build

node_modules
```

Comment: as of 2015, add `bower_components` ?

Comment: If you want to script it: `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/github/gitignore/master/Node.gitignore --no-check-certificate -O .gitignore` 8-)

Comment: Great!! This is exactly what I was looking for! It will be helpful to another kind of projects too, bc it has gitignore templates to various languages.

Tks a lot!!

Answer (score 10):

Easiest way to check that out is to look at the most popular Node.js modules on github:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/.gitignore 
https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/.gitignore 
https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/blob/master/.gitignore 
https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: @RicardoTomasi - What do you mean very specific? Then why do you include .DS_Store which is Mac specific?

Comment: Specific to the project. `.seed, .csv, .bin, .dat, .pid` files are not present in a common app. Just notice how they vary in the given examples - they only have `.DS_Store`, `npm-debug.log` and `node_modules` in common.

Answer (score 5):

As a start:

```
.DS_Store
thumbs.db
*.log
node_modules/
```

Add your `config.json`, compiled `.js` if you're using coffeescript, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> You can do it on the site **[gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io)**.

gitignore.io is a web service designed to help you create .gitignore files for your Git repositories. The site has a graphical and command line method of creating a .gitignore for your operating system, programming language, or IDE.

> **[Link](https://www.gitignore.io/api/node)** to .gitignore **only for Node.js**.

[Video tutorial](https://vimeo.com/204803019) for the service.

Answer (score 1):

commonly ignored files in NodeJs(check this [link](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Node.gitignore)):

```
# Logs
logs
*.log
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
lerna-debug.log*
.pnpm-debug.log*

# Diagnostic reports (https://nodejs.org/api/report.html)
report.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.json

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed
*.pid.lock

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage
*.lcov

# nyc test coverage
.nyc_output

# Grunt intermediate storage (https://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# Bower dependency directory (https://bower.io/)
bower_components

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directories
node_modules/
jspm_packages/

# Snowpack dependency directory (https://snowpack.dev/)
web_modules/

# TypeScript cache
*.tsbuildinfo

# Optional npm cache directory
.npm

# Optional eslint cache
.eslintcache

# Optional stylelint cache
.stylelintcache

# Microbundle cache
.rpt2_cache/
.rts2_cache_cjs/
.rts2_cache_es/
.rts2_cache_umd/

# Optional REPL history
.node_repl_history

# Output of 'npm pack'
*.tgz

# Yarn Integrity file
.yarn-integrity

# dotenv environment variable files
.env
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local
.env.local

# parcel-bundler cache (https://parceljs.org/)
.cache
.parcel-cache

# Next.js build output
.next
out

# Nuxt.js build / generate output
.nuxt
dist

# Gatsby files
.cache/
# Comment in the public line in if your project uses Gatsby and not Next.js
# https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-1#public-directory-support
# public

# vuepress build output
.vuepress/dist

# vuepress v2.x temp and cache directory
.temp
.cache

# Docusaurus cache and generated files
.docusaurus

# Serverless directories
.serverless/

# FuseBox cache
.fusebox/

# DynamoDB Local files
.dynamodb/

# TernJS port file
.tern-port

# Stores VSCode versions used for testing VSCode extensions
.vscode-test

# yarn v2
.yarn/cache
.yarn/unplugged
.yarn/build-state.yml
.yarn/install-state.gz
.pnp.*
```